# webkit-line-clamp: limit amount of lines with out ellipsis

Tags: html, css, formatting, webkit

I'm trying to limit the number of lines in my text area.
I follow this article:
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/css/how+to+show+specific+amount+of+multiline+text+in+html+css

```
.class{
   word-break: break-word;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   line-height: 16px; /* fallback */
   max-height: 32px; /* fallback */
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* number of lines to show */
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

it works, but I don't want ellipsis at the end of the text. Simply replacing `ellipsis` by `clip` doesn't work. How do I change it?

Here is a working example, both class a and class b give the same result:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GQI3IZL33M4T

```
<style> 
div.a {
    word-break: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

div.b {
    word-break: break-word;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
</style>
    
<h2>text-overflow: clip:</h2>
<div class="a">Hello world! Hello world! Hello world!Hello world! Hello world! Hello world!Hello world! Hello world! Hello world!Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world!Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world!Hello world! Hello world! Hello world!</div>

<h2>text-overflow: ellipsis:</h2>
<div class="b">Hello world! Hello world! Hello world!Hello world! Hello world! Hello world!Hello world! Hello world! Hello world!Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world!Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world! Hello world!Hello world! Hello world! Hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want the ellipsis you can just use a simple div with a fixed height, which is a multiple of your line height with overflow hidden. The div will wrap the text normally, and will hide anything that's overflown.

The only reason to use the `-webkit-line-clamp: 2;` solution is to automatically add the ellipsis. Otherwise don't use it.

Comment: ... or if you don't want a fixed height, or if you don't want to specify/know the line-height, or etc. That property being named line-clamp should point you in understanding THAT is totally NOT the ONLY reason.

Comment: Line-clamp adds ellipses. The question was about avoiding them. So the simplest solution is not to use it. It is easier to work around variable line height than removing the ellipses. I agree that based on the name it should only limit the number of lines, but that's not how it works. You are technically right that if for some reason you don't know your line height, using a fixed height can be difficult, but I'm curious what a real, non-hypothetical use-case is when line-height cannot be known? Doesn't sound realistic. Also your tone is just unprofessional beyond what's needed.